# How can I place the name of chart in the middle of it?

Tags: r

I did this analysis and make a chart but the name of the chart is in left side, how to place it in the middle?

```
qplot(data=d2, dist, xlab="Length of brake path (m)", ylab="Number of vehicles", main="Data from 1920")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
qplot(
    data = mtcars,
    as.factor(gear), 
    xlab = "Number of cylinders",
    ylab = "Number of vehicles",
    main = "Data from mtcars") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]